# View pager Recycler view Fragment transition with shared element

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I am new to fragment transitions and i am trying to add an animation along with a shared element to an image item from a recyclerview from a fragment contained in a viewpager and i don't know what i'm missing.

The transition works, the next fragment opens, but the element that i want to share does not change. In fact it is invisible on the next fragment.

I have the next structure:

- a main activity that contains the tablayout and the viewpager
- pagercontroller
- recyclerview adapter.
- 2 main fragments + another one that i want to open when i click an
  image item from the recyclerview

This is the onclick code in the recyclerview adapter's OnBindViewHolder :

```
holder.postimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity_Feed fragment1 = new Activity_Feed();
                Post fragment2 = new Post();

                Transition changeTransform = TransitionInflater.from((Activity)context).
                        inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);
                Transition explodeTransform = TransitionInflater.from((Activity)context).
                        inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode);

                fragment1.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransform);
                fragment1.setExitTransition(explodeTransform);

                fragment2.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeTransform);
                fragment2.setEnterTransition(explodeTransform);

                FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();

                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

                transaction.addSharedElement(holder.postimage, "imagetransition");
                transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);

                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2).addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();
            }

        });
```

And the transition resource change_image_transform :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeImageTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

I also set the transitionName on both fragments' images to "imagetransition".

I'm sure i'm missing something but i really don't know what.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you get any solution ?